# Filling the input of <form> with existing value

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a small issue. I've got a following form:

```
<form action="task.php" method="post">
   ID: <input id="iddev" type="text" name="id" disabled> <br/>
   Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat"> <br/>
   Longitude: <input type="text" name="lon"> <br/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Done!</button>
</form>
```

I would like to fill a disabled "id input" with an existing value that I have stored in my dropdown:

```
<?
foreach ($arajka as $a){
      echo  "<option data-id='" .$a['id'] ."' data-lat='" .$a['lat'] . "' data-lon='" .$a['lon'] . "'value=\"" .$a['id']. "\">" .$a['id']. "_" . $a['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

I mean I want this input to change as user selects other option from my dropdown menu. I'm already changing some stuff with JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$('#loc').change(function(){
    var lat = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-lat');
    var lon = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-lon');
            var id = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id');
    $('#mapka').html("<iframe width=\"425\" height=\"350\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" src=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"+lat+","+lon+"&amp;num=1&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed\"></iframe><br />");
            $('#iddev').html(id);
    });
});
```

Is there any option to do that? Am I missing something really simple? Or do I have to reload whole form?
Kind regards!

Comment: Don't you think you have Javascript and PHP mixed up? Your second code block is definitely a PHP snippet. Please try updating the value using jquery and if you are unable to do so, we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't update input fields with `.html()`. Try changing `.html()` to `.val()` in your dropdown code.

`$('#iddev').html(id);`

to

`$('#iddev').val(id);`

On a side note, you can grab data from the selected element by doing something like below, rather than finding the selected item 3 times and looking for specific data attributes.

```
// get all details bound to the selected option.
var mapDetails = $(this).find(':selected').data();

// lat
mapDetails.lat;

// long
mapDetails.lon;

// id
mapDetails.id;
```

Comment: THanks for answer. I found this out a while before but I still appreciate! :) got another problem. If my input is DISABLED I can't use it in form...it seems to be not passing data. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2987001 disabled controls are not successful. check out the spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `option:selected` instead of just `:selected`

```
var lat = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-lat');
var lon = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-lon');
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-id');
```

If the form is being loaded via ajax then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.quickviewLink a', function(e){

    });
});
```

Comment: it works for my <div id="mapka"> but it does not work for input id="iddev". I don't get why.